# Got a virus that i can't fix

Tags: internet, virus, blocking

i was using my computer then i got a pop up from my anti-virus avast that a malware attack was blocked then about 1min later a pop up on my computer (not from the internet) From a "Anti-virus" (it was named something close to Windows defender) that started "scanning" and found a ton of fake viruses.

i did not know it was on my computer so i just clicked the power off and turned it back on. when i logged in i waitted for my computer to load and then it poped back up and started the fake scan. so i tryed to open Task Manager and it said "task manager.exe is infected do you want to active anti-virus?" and it did that for every program i tryed to open.

So i asked around and they said to use Malare bytes to try to remove it. So i spent a long time trying to find a way to run it on the computer and found that the virus does not seem to work on other users, so i installed it and ran it, and it found it and deleted 6 virus

(i think it was like 1 file and 5 registry) i was thinking that was the end of it so i restarted. when i logged on there was no pop up and i searched with task manager and could not find any thing running that was not always there, but my internet wont work (i found that the virus blocked me from the interner when i had it like i.e and firefox, what i mean by blocked is it gives me "Web page can not be displayed") but some programs still can use the internet.

So my question is Do you think i removed it and how do i fix my internet so i can use it again. i Tryed to add all that i know about it, Ask if i missed anything. Btw i already tryed deleting cookies and all the saved stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often it is fastest to just save all your data (songs, pictures, documents, etc.) and re-install Windows and all of your programs.  This approach has multiple benefits.  It is likely to be just as fast as tracking down and eliminating the virus, it will eliminate any other viruses that you might not even know you have, and it makes your entire system fresh and clean.

Comment: :\ i really do not want to but i think you guys might be right.

Answer (score 1):

1.Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I like the KAspersky disc myself.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with Norton, these can be run once a week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each weekly scan.

Comment: Cheers! : -)...

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://cainternetsecurity.net/entscanner/

On trouble download http://www.avira.com/en/support-download-avira-antivir-rescue-system (a cute linux powered offline virus scanner)

Google any hit and search your backups ;)

Good luck

Comment: ok but how do i fix my internet?

Comment: btw the first link wont load the scanner :| and i am downloading the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend never trying to remove a virus, just reformat and reinstall your OS. If you partition your disk when you install it to keep the OS on one partition, and your home folder on another, then this becomes super easy and you don't lose anything.

It also means if you change your OS, then that's also seamless.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: ok i'll just reinstall (i can't partition the harddrive because it's too small) but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the network settings in your browsers are correct, for example, I.E. is normally set to automatically detect settings

Comment: i don't think that is it because it's not just i.e it's a lot of programs.